# Google Closure's Graphic module is too much slow. goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics

Tags: performance, html, canvas, google-closure

Recently, I study HTML Canvas using Google Closure.

but the performance of Google Closure is terribly slow.

when I run my code.. it almost crash down Chrome browser.

Of course I did the same thing in HTML Canvas code not using Google Closure; It is super fast.

Here is my canvas code using Google Closure (goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics)

Since I am just a beginner in this module(goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics), I am not sure I did it correctly. Is there a something wrong I did? 
Why is it so terribly slow??!!

It is too frustrating.

```
/** 
 * @param {Document} doct
 */
test.main = function(doct){
var dom = new goog.dom.DomHelper(doct);

/**
 * goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics(width, height, opt_coordWidth, opt_coordHeight, opt_domHelper)
 * @type {goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics} 
 */
var canvas = new goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics(500, 500, null, null, dom);
canvas.render(dom.getElement('canvasTest2'))
canvas.balls = [];






 function  drawScreen () {
    canvas.clear()

    for (var i =0; i <canvas.balls.length; i++) {
        ball = canvas.balls[i];
        ball.x += ball.xunits;
        ball.y += ball.yunits;
        var ellipse = canvas.drawEllipse(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, ball.radius, null, ball.solidFill);


        if (ball.x > canvas.width || ball.x < 0 ) {
            ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
            updateBall(ball);
        } else if (ball.y > canvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
            ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
            updateBall(ball); 
        }
    }

}

function updateBall(ball) {

    ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI/ 180;
    ball.xunits = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
    ball.yunits = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;

}

var numBalls = 80;
var maxSize = 15;
var minSize = 5;
var maxSpeed = maxSize+5;

for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {

    var tempRadius = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxSize)+minSize;
    var tempX = tempRadius*2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width)-tempRadius*2);
    var tempY = tempRadius*2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height)-tempRadius*2);
    var tempSpeed = maxSpeed-tempRadius;
    var tempAngle =  Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
    var tempRadians = tempAngle * Math.PI/ 180;
    var tempXunits = Math.cos(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
    var tempYunits = Math.sin(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;

    var stroke = new goog.graphics.Stroke(3, '#333');
    var solidFill = new goog.graphics.SolidFill('#333');

    tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY,radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, stroke:stroke, solidFill:solidFill, angle:tempAngle, xunits:tempXunits, yunits:tempYunits}

    canvas.balls.push(tempBall);

}

setInterval(drawScreen, 32);    


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe very obvious but did you tried it using Advanced Compilation? This removes dead code and optimizes your code. See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3 It might make the performance acceptable...

Regards,

Rene

Answer (score 3):

You should not call "drawEllipse" every time you render a frame with the closure library since this creates an element and adds it as a child to the canvas. Instead you should create the ellipses once and then loop over them using the "forEachChild" function. The performance of the above code is terrible because it is creating more and more children for the canvas each loop.

The following is the code for "drawEllipse" for reference:

```
/**
 * Draw an ellipse.
 *
 * @param {number} cx Center X coordinate.
 * @param {number} cy Center Y coordinate.
 * @param {number} rx Radius length for the x-axis.
 * @param {number} ry Radius length for the y-axis.
 * @param {goog.graphics.Stroke} stroke Stroke object describing the
 *    stroke.
 * @param {goog.graphics.Fill} fill Fill object describing the fill.
 * @param {goog.graphics.GroupElement=} opt_group The group wrapper
 *     element to append to.  If not specified, appends to the main canvas.
 *
 * @return {goog.graphics.EllipseElement} The newly created element.
 * @override
 */
goog.graphics.CanvasGraphics.prototype.drawEllipse = function(cx, cy, rx, ry,
    stroke, fill, opt_group) {
  var element = new goog.graphics.CanvasEllipseElement(null, this,
      cx, cy, rx, ry, stroke, fill);
  this.append(element, opt_group);
  return element;
};
```